# Intercepting Spring security in grails to get some request parameters

Tags: java, grails, internationalization, request

I would like to provide user possibility to select application language on login. But since we are using spring security I am really not sure how to get selected language parameter from request parameters?

Is there any way to intercept spring security authentication process without modifying the process itself (cause I have found some examples with custom authentication, but I don't need that at the moment)?

Or what would be the best practise to retrieve request parameter before it is redirected further? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your own (instead of default) Authentication Success Handler at `resources.groovy`:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
}
```

where `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is class that implements `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, or better to extends `AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that is used by default, like:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler(AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
    requestCache = ref('requestCache')
    defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl // '/'
    alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault // false
    targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter // 'spring-security-redirect'
    ajaxSuccessUrl = conf.successHandler.ajaxSuccessUrl // '/login/ajaxSuccess'
    useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer // false
    redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
}
```

This class have access to actual request at:

```
void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails already has built-in support for changing the user's language on every request independent of spring-security.  If you put a parameter called `lang` on any request, it will be intercepted and used to set the user's locale.

For example, you could put an input element on your login form that submits `lang=XX` where XX is a two character language code or a language/country combination like `en_GB`.  Grails will automatically update the locale associated with that session.  Note that this will override the `Accept-Language` header that the user's browser is probably already sending.

To update the locale manually, you can do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.LocaleEditor

def localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request)
def localeEditor = new LocaleEditor()
localeEditor.setAsText(params.lang)
localeResolver?.setLocale(request, response, localeEditor.value)
```

Comment: I've tried that, first of all by adding form action="${postUrl}?lang=es, parameter was posted to the server but nothing happened. And also I've tried to create a drop down (which I still need) with element name="lang" and possible languages. It was sent in the request, but also nothing happened.

Comment: Interesting, spring-security seems to bypass the i18n stuff; normally, `ParamsAwareLocaleChangeInterceptor` would handle this.  It looks like you have to do it yourself in an `AuthenticationSuccess` event handler as per Igor Artamonov's answer.

Comment: It might be because of POST request and not GET request..thou I didn't found any reference about it in the documentation. Can you comment on your approach to set locale. Does this contains any advantages over doing it like that: session['org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE'] = new Locale("es", "PR") ?

Comment: The `LocaleResolver` simply hides the details of how the locale is stored.  By default it uses the session as above, but there are drop-in replacements for using e.g. cookies.

Comment: I see.., unfortunately, for some reason localeResolver is null if I am using your method (is it necessary to register localeResolver in resources.groovy, I think not?). Also request.params is null, so I can only get parameter using request.getParameter("lang"). Thank you for your help anyway!