# Where to put custom post-authentication logic in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to put a little bit of extra logic after an authentication attempt (to record the IP and result in the database, to serve later to detect brute force attacks).

I read [Intercepting Spring security in grails to get some request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982372/intercepting-spring-security-in-grails-to-get-some-request-parameters) but that approach only allows a handler for successful authentication because this is waht `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` defines `onAuthenticationSuccess()`. I need both.

I'm fairly new to Grails and its security plugin so while I'm sure this is possible, I'm not sure about which place is best. A filter? A service (then which one?) ? A controller?

Thank you in advance.

Environment: Grails 2.3, Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM :)  See the section on events: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/7%20Events.html